# AS3 call function upon clicking a line from a textfield

Tags: string, actionscript-3, function, line, textfield

**How do you call a different function when a line of text from a TextField/TextArea is clicked?**

I already have a function which retrieves a description when any point of the TextField is clicked:

```
list.text = "chicken";
list.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getter);

var descriptionArray:Array = new Array();
descriptionArray[0] = ["potato","chicken","lemon"];//words
descriptionArray[1] = ["Round and Brown","Used to be alive","Yellow"];//descriptions

function getter(e:MouseEvent):void
{

    for (var i:int = 0; i < descriptionArray.length; i++)
    {
        var str:String = e.target.text;//The text from the list textfield
        if (str == descriptionArray[0][i]) //if the text from List is in the array
        {
            trace("found it at index: " + i);
            description.text = descriptionArray[1][i];//displays "Used to be alive".
        }
        else
        {
            trace(str+" != "+descriptionArray[0][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, and returns the correct description.

But **I want it to instead retrieve a different description depending on what line in the TextField/TextArea was clicked**, like, if I used `list.text = "chicken\npotato"`

I know I can use multiple textfields to contain each word, but the list might contain over 100 words, and I want to use the TextArea's scrollbar to scroll through the words in the list, and if I used multiple textfields/areas, each one would have its own scrollbar, which is pretty pointless.

**So, how do I call a different function depending on what line I clicked?**

PS: It's not technically a different function, it's detecting the string in the line that was clicked, I just put it that way for minimal confusion.

Comment: is the textfield/area editable?

Comment: Nope, the textfield/area is just Dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few built-in methods that should make your life easier:

```
function getter(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // find the line index at the clicked point
    var lineIndex:int = list.getLineIndexAtPoint(e.localX, e.localY);
    // get the text at that line index
    var itemText:String = list.getLineText(lineIndex).split("\n").join("").split("\r").join("");

    // find the text in the first array (using indexOf instead of looping)
    var itemIndex:int = descriptionArray[0].indexOf(itemText);

    // if the item was found, you can use the sam index to 
    // look up the description in the second array
    if(itemIndex != -1)
    {
        description.text = descriptionArray[1][itemIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I never knew those functions existed. Thanks a whole lot, that saves me from a giant mess :)

Comment: Happy to help. Here's a link to the Adobe AS3 Reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html